# How do I call a specific hero missing?

Tags: dota-2

I know that there's a "Missing" command in the Chat Wheel that will report your lane missing, but that only does "Missing Top!" or "Missing Middle!" messages it seems. I've seen people call specific heroes missing before though:

[image: A built-in message saying "Riki is missing!"]

How are they doing this? Is it some kind of hotkey I haven't found? Is it some complicated custom bind? Is it just something simple that I'm missing?

Comment: @spartacus, my question is more general.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To call specific people missing, all you have to do is hold Alt and click their hero icon at the top:

[image: A picture highlighting Riki's hero icon]

Then you'll get a nice message like you described instead of the general lane one.

Also, besides just being able to call people missing, you can also announce that someone has returned by holding Ctrl+Alt and clicking their hero icon in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 14):

From my experience i would guess:

**Hero is missing**
Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click portrait.

**Hero is back**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click portrait.

Similar concept to switching between map flare types.

**Attack/Defend Flare**
Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and click map.

**Move flare**
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + click map

According to the [First Blood](http://www.dota2.com/firstblood) update:

> Alt-left clicking on an enemy icon in the top bar will send a chat message that the hero is missing

And according to [this recent update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/12341/):

> Alt+Control clicking enemy heroes in the top bar now sends a hero has returned chat message